# Pinescript v5 - Why does "type" create integer series at init?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

The problem is in the title =)

> Why does "type" create integer series at init?

I already search on internet and forums (nothing found), also ask to some AI (useless)
I try to use string, then convert it, but every tests have same error result

Can anyone know the reason why and have a solution?

This is the sample code:

```
//@version=5
strategy('Test', overlay = true)

type objSetted
    int _test    = 21
    float _test2 = 2.0

// Create and set an objSetted
var objSetted OBJ_A = objSetted.new(_test=90)

// Get rsiPeriod (_test for example)
// > OBJ_A is global and init ONCE, so not a serie
// /!\ ERROR: "An argument of 'series int' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected."
var int rsiPeriod = int(OBJ_A._test)

// Do calcul on close values
float r = ta.rsi(close, rsiPeriod)

// Display
plot(r)

// Do other thing
var int otherValue = int(OBJ_A._test2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you use the `var` keyword to initialize it once does not make it of type `simple`. That is because at any point you can do `OBJ_A._test := 0` and change its value.

However, values of "simple" can never change during the execution of the script. Built-in variables that depend on your chart are usually of type "simple". E.g. `syminfo.*`, `timeframe.*`, `ticker.*` families.

You can read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Type_system.html) to get more information about the type system.